# how to make sure that all textbox are filled before saving in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I'm new to vb and trying to figure things out via searching the net or asking colleagues but now I hit a dead end. I want to have my program to make sure that all my textboxes are filled before saving into the db.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CmdSave_Click()

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
    .Open "Select * from table1", cn, 2, 3
        If LblAdd_Edit.Caption = "ADD" Then
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save this new rocord?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "FJD Inventory") = vbNo Then: Exit Sub
    .AddNew
        !Type = TxtName.Text
    !System = txtsys.Text
    !acc = TxtAcc.Text
    !owner = TxtOwn.Text
    !dept = TxtDpt.Text
    !svctag = txtSvcTag.Text
    .Update
    Else
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save this changes?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "FJD Inventory") = vbNo Then: Exit Sub
    Do While Not .EOF

    If LvList.SelectedItem.Text = !Type Then
        !Type = TxtName.Text
        !System = txtsys.Text
        !acc = TxtAcc.Text
        !owner = TxtOwn.Text
        !dept = TxtDpt.Text
        !svctag = txtSvcTag.Text
        .Update

    Exit Do
    Else
    .MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
    End If


    End With

    Form_Activate
    Save_Cancel

End Sub
```

---

I was trying to  add the following

```
If TxtName.Text = "" Or txtsys.Text = "" Or TxtAcc.Text = "" Or TxtOwn.Text = "" Or TxtDpt.Text = "" Or txtSvcTag.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("All Fields Required", vbCritical, "Error") = vbOK: Exit Sub
```

When I run the program I get a compile error
function or call on the left-hand side of assignment must return a variant or object. I use that msgbox function all the time but now its the line I get an error

Answer (score 2):

```
If TxtName.Text = "" Or txtsys.Text = "" Or TxtAcc.Text = "" Or TxtOwn.Text = "" Or TxtDpt.Text = "" Or txtSvcTag.Text = "" Then
    If MsgBox("All Fields Required", vbCritical, "Error") = vbOK Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution. It uses a function to check each textbox on the form and demonstrates using the function. I also compare the text length rather than the text to an empty string because (in general) numeric comparisons are faster than string comparisons.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    If ValidateTextFields Then
        MsgBox "Your changes have been saved."
    Else
        MsgBox "All fields are required."
    End If

End Sub

Private Function ValidateTextFields() As Boolean
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim result As Boolean

    result = True        'set this to false if a textbox fails
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            If Len(ctrl.Text) = 0 Then
                result = False
                Exit For 'bail on the first failure
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
    ValidateTextFields = result

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB6, you can use `Trim()` function so that spaces not considered as characters.

```
If (Trim$(txtGOSID.Text) = "") Then
msgBox "Please provide input.", vbExclamation
```

With the `$` sign, `Trim()` returns a `String` value directly; without the `$`
sign, `Trim()` returns a `Variant` with a sub-type of String.